# Validation fires even if whole TR is display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have one table row as below

```
<tr id="trEm">
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmNumber" runat="server" Width="200" ToolTip="Enter Acknowledgement No." CssClass="body_text capital" MaxLength="16" TabIndex="6"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEm1Number" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="first" ErrorMessage="EM Part-I No. is required" ControlToValidate="txtEmNumber" Display="None" Text="*">
   <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsFirstPanel" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" ValidationGroup="first" />
</tr>
```

I have applied some logic with jQuery that apply css on this row for display like

```
if ($(value).val() == '0' && $(value).is(':checked')) {       
   $('#trEm').css('display', 'none');
}
```

This is functioning fine, however, validation fires of required field even `trEm` is (display:none).

What to do to prevent this validation when this row is in invisible mode ??

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
   $('#trEm').is(':visible')
   {
       if ($(value).val() == '0' && $(value).is(':checked')) 
         {       
            $('#trEm').css('display', 'none');
         }
   }
```

Comment: @AijazChauhan what about now.? is this fine.?

Comment: stil i don't get it, validation fires for text box , even the row is invisible.

Comment: I need some logic that prevent validation when trEm set to display:none

Comment: @AijazChauhan Sorry i just provided a id selector without `#` Now try.

Comment: @AijazChauhan Can you make a demo of your situation, so that we could fix your issue easily.?

Answer (score 0):

You can check wheter an element is visible via jQuery:

```
selector = '#yourDiv';
var visible = $(selector).is(":visible");
```

As your working with mobile devices you can rely on modern browser. Otherwise this solution wouldn't work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here it is

```
            $('[Id$="ibtnSubmitFirstPanel"]').click(function () {
                var controles = [];
                var visible;

                for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {

                    var a = $('#' + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).parent().parent().attr("id");
                    if (typeof a !== 'undefined' && a !== false) {

                        controles.push(Page_Validators[i]);
                    }
                }
                $.each(controles, function (key, value) {

                    visible = $(controles[key]).parent().parent().is(':visible');
                    ValidatorEnable(controles[key], visible);

                })

                return Page_ClientValidate("first");
            });
```

Please refer to it